# Help With Solving Trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

$(\sin x)^2 - 5\sin x \cos x=0$

What would be the first atep to solve this. I normally get the equation into a quadratic one but I cannot seem to spot the first step here.

What I mean by $(\sin x)^2$ incase there will be confusion is "Sin squared x"

Appreciate any help.

Comment: But you haven't posted an equation?!

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  We talk of solving equations, but you don't have an equation to solve.  Do you mean that $\sin^2 (x) - 5\sin(x) \cos(x) = 0$?

Comment: Please check the equation - I have added $=0$ - is this what you intended?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: What you have is
$$\sin x \cdot (\sin x - 5\cos x) = 0$$

Now one of the factors must be zero, and when can that happen?